# include for all files

Tags: php, wamp

I have a 'template.php' file which I manually `include` in most of my php files - is there a way to somehow automatically `include` a php file into all of my other files?

I could not find any examples that worked for me.

Comment: You can use the .htaccess or php  pear package setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `.htaccess` file to your directory and use the following

```
php_value auto_prepend_file template.php
```

You can also read about `PHP's` `auto_prepend_file directive` [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)